# Look ahead not working in QRegExp?

Tags: c++, regex, qt, regex-lookarounds

I'm new to regexp and I'm trying to use the lookahead assert feature in QRegExp to check the length of a string. Here is a very simple example:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  QRegExp regexp("(?=^.{0,5}$)[0-9]*");
  qDebug() << "result:" << regexp.exactMatch("12345");
  return 1;
}
```

which prints: "result: false".

I tested this regexp and the string on this webpage: http://regexpal.com/, and it shows match.

Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: My RegExp knowledge is damn poor, but I noticed in the docs that there are 2 versions of RegExp pattern syntaxes which relate to 'greedy quantifiers'.  Is your test applicable to that?  Docs: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qregexp.html#greedy-quantifiers

Comment: Your regex is fine, but some regex engines will not work with variable length lookaround assertions. QRegExp is probably one of them.

Comment: Did you ever try dropping the leading `^`, and trying `"^(?=.{0,5}$)\d*"`?

Answer (score 0):

For me, with QT 4.8.6, it results correctly in "result: true". No matter, if you put the  `^` inside the look ahead or before, as FrankieTheKneeMan suggested.